# Como forçar um download com ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, download

Estou utilizando a classe DOMPDF do PHP para gerar relatórios de contas a receber com filtros dinâmicos.

O usuário seleciona os filtros em um form e pede para gerar, até ai tudo bem. Mas ele terá a opção de exportar o que ele filtrou em PDF.

Hoje, tenho o seguinte código jQuery:

```
$('#exportPDF').click(function(){
        var relatorio = $('.relatorios').html();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "acao.php?acao=exportPDF",
            data: 'relatorio='+relatorio,
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loader').fadeIn(500);
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loader').fadeOut(500);
            },
            success: function (retorno) {
                console.log(retorno);
                $('.relatorios').html(retorno);

                // RETORNA MENSAGEM DE SUCESSO
                $.gritter.add({
                    title: 'Sucesso',
                    text: 'O download irá iniciar em breve.',
                    class_name: 'success'
                 });
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

E tenho o seguinte código em PHP:

```
// Inclui classe DOMPDF
        require_once("../../../include/class/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");

        // Recebe a tabela
        $relatorio = $_POST['relatorio'];

        $dompdf = new DOMPDF();

        $dompdf->load_html($relatorio);
        $dompdf->render();
        $dompdf->stream('relatorio_cliente.pdf');
```

A ideia seria que ao gerar o PDF pelo PHP o Ajax enviasse para o browser/client a requisição de download e todo o processo fluir. Já tentei utilizar os headers no próprio PHP e no Ajax, entre diversas outras coisas. Também já procurei por isso na internet e já encontrei alguns problemas iguais ao meu, só não entendi muito bem.

Tem como fazer isso?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se não me engano, isso que você está fazendo chega a funcionar em alguns browsers, mas não em outros. Uma alternativa é continuar fazendo a requisição ajax, e salvar o PDF em disco em vez de tentar servi-lo como retorno dessa requisição. Em vez disso, passe a URL do arquivo salvo como resposta, e na função `success` do ajax use `window.location = retorno`.

Comment: pensei nessa questão, o problema é que com o tempo o servidor iria lotar com os arquivos salvos, a não ser que eu criasse uma função para apagar todos os arquivos de X em X dias. Qual a sua opinião?

Comment: Você pode agendar uma tarefa no servidor, rodando todo dia e apagando arquivos mais antigos que 1 dia, ou algo assim.

Comment: Sim, perfeito. Vou adotar a sua sugestão,  obrigado @bfavaretto

Answer (score 1):

Eu já fiz isso e não consegui também. O AJAX não recebe PDF. Nesse caso, não utilizei o ajax. Fiz apenas abrir em uma nova página (_blank) forçar o download e depois que o download fosse efetuado a página era fechada automáticamente.

Comment: Sim, mas como vou fazer essa pagina receber o conteúdo de um determinada tabela?  Pois com o ajax, eu pego o html inteiro da tabela e gero o pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Eu passei por um problema parecido. Depois de procurar um pouco (muito) na net, achei este plugin: [**jQuery File Download**](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) (recomendo utilizar juntamente com este: [**jQuery URL Decoder**](http://urldecoderonline.com/js/jquery.urldecoder.min.js))

A utilização é bem simples, mas tem um macetezinho que me deu muita dor de cabeça até encontrar:

1. Referencie o plugin `jquery.urldecoder.min.js`
2. Referencie o plugin `jquery.fileDownload.js`

Exemplo do meu código:

```
var url = $.url.parse(window.location.href);

var href = $.url.build({
    protocol: url.protocol, //http|https
    host: url.host, //localhost|contoso.com
    port: url.port, //porta do web server 
    path: url.path + 'pdf.php', // url que receberá a requisição
    params: {
        param1: 'val1',
        param2: 'val2',
        param3: 'val3',
        paramN: 'valN',
    }
});
// output:
// http:// localhost:80/pdf.php?param1=param1&param2=param2&param3=param3

// prepara um modal de aviso ao usuário informando que o arquivo está sendo gerado (bootstrap)
var preparingFileModal = $("#preparing-file");
preparingFileModal.modal();

$.fileDownload(href, {
    successCallback: function(url) {
        // após a requisição ser completada com sucesso, fecha o modal
        setTimeout(function() {
            preparingFileModal.modal('hide');
        }, 3000);
    },
    failCallback: function(url) {
        // caso haja um erro na requisição, altera a mensagem do modal para callback do usuário
        preparingFileModal.find('.modal-body p').first().html('Ocorreu um erro ao tentar baixar o PDF.\n\nTente novamente mais tarde');
    }
});
```